# Empty results from analytics reporting api when requesting device dimension with userGender in php

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

i am getting report for device dimension  but when i extend one more dimension usergender, i get empty response in php.
i was expecting to get response of both dimension if one is empty then show response of another dimension. i have also used setIncludeEmptyRows but it did'nt work for me.

Comment: Have you enabled Google Signals in your property?

Comment: yes, actually i have multiple routes and i want if a route has a empty dimension then return response of null value for that dimension only.